# Getting error on Style.xml in android

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

My problem is that i am getting error on `styles.xml` in my android project.May be due to that my `R.java` is not generating.I am using Support library `appcompact_V7` support library.  Can anyone specify what error I made in my program.  Here is my code....

#### Styles.xml

```
 <resources>

        <!--
            Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
            by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
        -->


{ AT THE BELOW LINE I AM GETTING THE ERROR}

        <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <!--
                Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
                res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
                backward-compatibility can go here.
            -->
        </style>

        <!-- Application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
            <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        </style>

    </resources>
```

My android `manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bq.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Image"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Have you properly add `appcompact` library to your project? Also your class must extends with `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: Try to replace android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" with this android:theme="@style/AppTheme".

Comment: @Rockstar-.I correctly added it

Comment: HareshChhelana:I changed it inside android manifest as you suggest,but it is not working in my case ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the style to 
`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">` 
instead of 
`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">`

And if you are still facing error like `No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package` , then just remove `android:showAsAction="never"` from res/menu folder from every xml file.

Comment: @Jack, whether it works for you or not ? If yes, then please accept the answer !!

Comment: :Some internet problems occurs ...you are correct,it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

in our **style.xml** change first style tag as follow:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

Comment: yes,This is the error
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.bq.sample'

Comment: Thankyou Abu Saleh Musa

Answer (score 0):

I got the error that
cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'

I'm not sure is it same problem with you.
This method solved my problem.

1. Go to your project directory (or to Project View)
2. Find and open .idea directory
3. Remove caches and libraries directories <-- this is essential
4. Invalidate Caches / Restart

Ref: [https://github.com/red5pro/streaming-android/issues/31](http://I%20got%20the%20error%20that%20%20cannot%20resolve%20symbol%20%27Theme.AppCompat.Light%27%20%20I%27m%20not%20sure%20is%20it%20same%20problem%20with%20you.%20This%20method%20solved%20my%20problem.%20%201.%20Go%20to%20your%20project%20directory%20(or%20to%20Project%20View)%202.%20Find%20and%20open%20.idea%20directory%203.%20Remove%20caches%20and%20libraries%20directories%20%3C--%20this%20is%20essential%204.%20Invalidate%20Caches%20/%20Restart%20%20https://github.com/red5pro/streaming-android/issues/31)